# TItanium JS: How to add active states to buttons int he header bar for iOS

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I'm looking to add an active state to a `systemButton` in the header bar of an iOS app using Appcelerator Titanium.

I want to achieve the same result as the the Calendar with the list view activated in iOS8. As you can see the below the list icon has an active state, whereby it has an orange background.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using iOS System Buttons in the header of an app?

Thanks, Owen

Comment: i dont think it can be done for System Buttons , for normal buttons you could have changed the color at onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must manually keep track of the states of the button for a Toggle effect. This does not work with a `systemButton`.

example:

```
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'Off', isOn: false });
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.source.isOn) {
        e.source.title = 'Off';
        e.source.isOn = false;
    } else {
        e.source.title = 'On';
        e.source.isOn = true;
    }
});
```